# Why does python list does not have len() method

Tags: python, list

Python's length of list can be calculated by len(a_list). My question is, why was a_list.len() not implemented? Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: because the people writing the language decided it would not add any value to the language ...

Comment: It's asking something about the language, which might be more appropriate on programmers.

Comment: they have a `list.__len__` method, which `len(list)` calls

Comment: a_list.len() looks more intuitive to me than len(a_list), hence the question. Previous answers, which this question is sighted as duplicated, does not answer the reason other than the no value in adding extra len() method.

Comment: There's also an official [FAQ entry](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list) on this.

Comment: As far s the user is concerned it is best to have a standard operation that handles everything and the individual type processing is encapsulated.

Comment: `from forbiddenfruit import curse;curse(list,"len",len)` is a neat trick/hack if you really want to be able to do this (`[1,2,3].len()`) @dt369 (youll need https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit )

Comment: In the artical  [why does python use methods for some functionality eg list index but functions for other eg len list](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm) a good reasoning is given: _some operators read better a prefix then postfix like len()._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

likely just because its redundant when we already have and are use to len() maybe you could add a .len() method :)

there is a a_list.__len__()